# How to update specific object inside the array?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a data that looks like below in MongoDB

```
{
_id: aasdfeasfeasdf,
todo: [
         {_todoIde: 333, _with: []},
         {_todoIde: 111, _with: []},
      ]
}
```

I want to `$addToSet` value to `_todoIde: 333`'s `_with` like `{_todoIde: 333, _with: [aaaa]},`. How can I do it?

```
.updateOne(
   {_id},
   { $addToSet: {}}
)
```

I got to the document but I can't specify that `_todoIde: 333` to update just that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an extra condition to specify the `todoIde`

Try this:

```js
db.collection.update(
            {$and:[{_id: typeId},{'todo._todoIde': 333}]},
            {$set: { "todo._todoIde.$._with":[a,b,c]}},
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

The positional [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html) operator identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array,

```
.updateOne(
  { _id: "aasdfeasfeasdf", "todo._todoIde": 333 },
  {
    $addToSet: {
      "todo.$._with": "aaaa"
    }
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vQ-SwH1GsZC)